# Ruby on Rails - Carrierwave - Blank/Empty images with resize_to_fill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm currently implementing CarrierWave into my app. A problem I noticed is that most images I've uploaded fail to correctly generate a thumbnail size (64x64).

I'm using `resize_to_fit` and `resize_to_fill` for different versions, and the `resize_to_fill` (for cropping) is failing most of the time.

Here I've generated two versions, gallery and thumb.

[image: explorer]

// image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    storage :file

    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end


    version :gallery do
        process resize_to_fit: [400, 300]
    end

    version :thumb do
        process :resize_to_fill => [64, 64]
    end

    def extension_whitelist
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end
end
```

They look correct; however, if you actually open thumb within Paint, it's completely blank.

[image]

I've tested this with a bunch of different pictures, and most have this happen. But I did notice that if I open the main image, save it (without doing anything), then recreate the versions, it's fixed. Must be something with how it's being saved, or something.

Here is the [source image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0ex7gs5wa71idu/low-poly-texture-2.png) that I've been able to reproduce this issue with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange behavior. I was very curious about this problem, so I made very simple example on my dev. machine referencing Ryan's Bates
[cropping images episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised).

You can just follow up, it may help you.

Let's say we generated simple user scaffold, and we have in our DB fields called :name and :avatar of string types.

In our User model we'll mount uploader and create virtual attributes:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
end
```

Method create in **users_controller.rb** will look like this (including strong params):

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    if params[:user][:avatar].present?
      render :crop  # Render crop template
    else
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Successfully created user."
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end

# Strong params# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit!
end
```

The **image_uploader.rb** you posted was good. I will just post mine, as I made large and thumb versions and used `resize_to_limit` process
instead of `resize_to_fit`:

```
version :large do
  resize_to_limit(400, 300)
end

version :thumb do
  resize_to_fill(64, 64)
end
```

We can create now **crop.html.erb** template in `views/users` folder and populate with code below:

```
<h1>Crop Avatar</h1>

<%= image_tag @user.avatar_url(:large) %>

<h4>Preview</h4>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden">
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:large) %>
</div>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% %w[x y w h].each do |attribute| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}" %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Crop" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When you create new user form it will have avatar attachment. When you upload photo and submit it, it will trigger 
`def create` method and it will check if params are presented, and render the **crop.html.erb** template:

```
if params[:user][:avatar].present?
  render :crop  # Render crop template
else
```

I haven't included in this example [Jcrop library](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html) for cropping images, this was very simple example. At the end it should crop `64x64` pixels
by default.

There is also [CarrierWave extension](https://github.com/kirtithorat/carrierwave-crop) to crop uploaded images using Jcrop plugin with preview, which I haven't tried.

I hope it helps